# Regex Notation in RFC

Tags: json, parsing, grammar, context-free-grammar

What does the following mean in the JSON rfc?

```
  number = [ minus ] int [ frac ] [ exp ]
  ...
  exp = e [ minus / plus ] 1*DIGIT
  frac = decimal-point 1*DIGIT
```

I assume `1*DIGIT` means "One or more digits", but why that particular notation, why not as `\d+` or `DIGIT+` or something else. Or does `1*DIGIT` mean something else?

Source: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8259

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it means "one or more DIGIT". The formalism used in RFCs is itself described in an RFC, specifically [RFC-5234](https://www.rfc-editor.org/info/rfc5234), which you'll find in the Normative References of the RFC you're looking at. It's also noted in section 1.1 of the RFC, "Conventions used in this document".

Comment: great thanks. This part is where it says it: `Default values are 0 and infinity so that *<element> allows any
   number, including zero; 1*<element> requires at least one;
   3*3<element> allows exactly 3; and 1*2<element> allows one or two.`